# How to get all commits committed to a branch which is already merged to master

Tags: git

I have a commit history like following:

```
A---B---C---D---E---F---J---K---L---M master
     \         /               /    
      G---H---I-----------N---O       bugfix
```

`bugfix` branch is based on commit `B` on `master` branch. It was merged many times to the `master`. Meanwhile there were other commits on `master`.

I want to get all the commits committed to `bugfix` branch `G`, `H`, `I`, `N` and `O`. Better as a patch file, much better including all commit messages so that after applying the patch I get 3 commits with the original messages. However, it is ok if I can get only the commit hashes without all those extra wishes.

The commits shouldn't include `A` and `B` although the `bugfix` branch is based on `B`.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git format-patch I -3`

You could use `git am` to apply these patches.

In some cases, the commit log message's subject might be formatted like `[FEATURE][3348]add log-out in the menu`, which includes `[` and `]`. You need to add `--keep-non-patch` in `git am` to keep the [] parts.

Updated:
If you need all commits, `git format-patch A..M` or `git format-patch A..HEAD`. If A is needed, `git format-patch --root M` or `git format-patch --root HEAD` or just `git format-patch --root`.

`git format-patch -$(git log --oneline | wc -l)` seems also okay, which includes A.patch.

If you need only the commits of bugfix, `git format-patch B..O`

Comment: Thank you, but I want to get all commits, and the commit history is not so simple as I draw on the question. It was just as a representation.

Comment: I just want to get all commits on the bugfix branch, after the branch is created. Meanwhile is the branch a few times merged to the master branch.

Comment: @ЕлинЙ. You mean G H I N and O?

Comment: Yes. I updated and enhanced the question, so that it is clearer.